# Solr boost with product of constant score queries: How to use the filterCache?

Tags: solr, lucene, ranking

We [boost](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/other-parsers.html#boost-query-parser) our documents by three criterias which are nearly independent of the [main query](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/the-standard-query-parser.html):

1. Boostfactor 100 for relevant versions of the document (vs. obsolete versions) (query A)
2. Boostfactor 30 for documents with special keywords (query B)
3. Boostfactor 2.2 for documents form a specific geographic region (query C)

At time our query looks like this:

> select?q={!boost b=product(if(exists(query($bq0)),100.0,1),if(exists(query($bq1)),30.0,1),if(exists(query($bq2)),2.2,1))}(search main query)&bq0=(query A)&bq1=(query B)&bq2=(query C)

or alternativly

> select?q={!boost b=product(query($bq0),query($bq1),query($bq2))}(search main query)&bq0=(query A)^=100.0&bq1=(query B)^=30.0&bq2=(query C)^=2.2

Our goal is to use the filterCache for the [Constant Score queries](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/the-standard-query-parser.html#constant-score-with).

So any ideas to make this boosting fast?

In elasticsearch I would use [function_score with boost_mode multiply](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html).
Now I wonder if there is a BooleanQuery which multiply the score/weight of the ShouldClauses. If there would be this I could use the [filter(…​) syntax](http://yonik.com/solr/query-syntax/#FilterQuery) to ensure that the filter-cache is used.

Back to the question:

How to boost with the [product](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/function-queries.html#product-function) of three [Constant Score queries](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/the-standard-query-parser.html#constant-score-with) on a fast (=cached) way?

Comment: Would using [the `boost` parameter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html#TheExtendedDisMaxQueryParser-TheboostParameter) (which can be given multiple times) from edismax with a constant score operator work?

Comment: Hi MatsLindh, yes this would work. But under the hood the result is the same with the same performance issues:  [source code](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/7.4.0/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/ExtendedDismaxQParser.java#L435)

Answer (score 0):

The "solution":

> select?q={!boost b=product(def(query($bq0),1.0),def(query($bq1),1.0),def(query($bq2),1.0))}(search main query)&bq0=(filter(query A))^=100.0&bq1=(filter(query B))^=30.0&bq2=(filter(query C))^=2.2

but this solution is slow if the queries are not in the FilterCache at first time.

Why it is slow? Because [FilterQuery](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/7.4.0/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/query/FilterQuery.java#L90) will compute each DocSet even if 90% of the docs in this DocSet are not hits of the main query (without [filter-Syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/the-standard-query-parser.html#differences-between-lucene-s-classic-query-parser-and-solr-s-standard-query-parser) all computations are skipped for docs that are no hits of the main query).

Btw. why are [facets](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/faceting.html) compute in multi-threaded ("facet.threads") and [filter-queries](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/common-query-parameters.html#fq-filter-query-parameter) are not?